# check if mouse is over an object

Tags: jquery

I am working to modify a script,

Here is original lines;

```
function JT_init(){
       $("a.jTip")
       .hover(function(){JT_show(this.href,this.id,this.name)},function(){$('#JT').remove()})
           .click(function(){return false});       
}
```

I am trying to do;

```
function JT_init(){
       $("a.jTip")
       .hover(function(){JT_show(this.href,this.id,this.name)},function(){checkifhover()})
           .click(function(){return false});       
}


function checkifhover() {
//if there was a func like ismouseover i would do this...

if ismouseover(JT) {
return false;
} else {
$('#JT').remove();
}
}
```

how can i check if mouse is over ?

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the mouseover() event (http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)?

Comment: not really, i am looking for sth inform me if the mouse is over an object

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the element that you show at mouseover is a child of the element that you hook up the event to. That way you are still hovering the parent as long as you are hovering the child.